# How to customize the admin page of strapi?

Tags: strapi

I am using strapi in one of my projects and it is good to use but the problem is I am not able to customize the admin page. My operating system is windows 10. Whenever I make any changes in the source code and run `npm run setup` or `npm run build` on the command line to make those changes reflect in the build file,  it gives the following error : `'APP_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. 
Has anyone came across similar issue and was able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have this error too
`npm run setup error 'APP_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command`
i use windows 10 x64 and `npm` version `6.4.1` and `MongoDB` shell version `v4.0.10`.
I have Error on `admin/scripts/setup.js`.
my problem **Solved** by added `set` key to commands(two line)

```
" && APP_PATH="${appPath}" npm run build`
```

to

```
" && set APP_PATH="${appPath}" npm run build`
```